# SQL Select latest post by postID

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, select

I am wanting to display in the footer when the most recent message was posted.
eg: last post Saturday, 23 July 2011 03:02 p.m.

I am using ASP.Net 4.0, Visual Studio and MSSQL Server Management Studio.

Sql Tables

postID | postCreated

19 | Saturday, 23 July 2011 01:02 p.m.

20 | Saturday, 23 July 2011 02:02 p.m.

21 | Saturday, 23 July 2011 03:02 p.m.

postID is Int and is set as the primary key, and auto increments.
postCreated is Varchar.

What I have tried so far

SELECT max(postID) from "Table"

this shows me the most Recent postID, but I want to extend this to grab the most recent postCreated associated to that ID

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sql query:

```
 SELECT * FROM Table WHERE postID = (SELECT max(postID) from Table)
```

Comment: LIMIT isn't supported by SQL Server. Use TOP instead.

Comment: A subquery isn't required here. Just select the top row, ordered by date descending.

Comment: @ShadowChaser ORDER BY is slower than a sub query though. `SELECT max(postID) from Table` is nearly instant and requires no hard disk access since postId is (I'm assuming) an index.

Comment: True, but generally the posting date should be indexed anyhow. However if we assume it isn't, the subquery still doesn't get any performance advantage over TOP 1 with the key column. The SQL Server Execution plan of both queries is exactly the same - SELECT, TOP, CLUSTERED INDEX SCAN. 

Effectively the subquery version is internally changed into the TOP/ORDER BY by the SQL Server optimizer. The subquery is less readable with no benefit.

Comment: @ShadowChaser To me the subquery is more readable because it uses a comparison operator and is clear you want exactly maximum postID. It's not like either aren't very readable though :) I realize that's just a personally opinion and this is no place for opinionated discussions. So we might as well just leave it at that :)

Comment: Ill give you a +1 considering it looks like you weren't downvoted for a valid reason. The solution is correct just not optimal, doesn't deserve a down vote for that.

Answer (score 3):

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY postID DESC

Comment: this is most efficient.  It takes advantage of the primary key.  It is however DEPENDENT upon records being posted in order. Or more narrowly, that the last record in the table IS the most recent post.

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 * from Table t order by t.postID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Select tn.postCreated
    From table_name tn
   Where tn.postId = 
          (Select Max(postId)
             From table_name);
```